# What is the algorithm by which Wifite work?

Tags: kali-linux, aircrack-ng

I tried wifite in Kali Linux and I was curious about the algorithm by which it works and other dictionary-based wifi cracking tools.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, `wifte` is a kind of wrapper for different tools like: `aircrack-ng`, like the documenations says:

> Wifite is a python script which automates the WEP and WPA cracking process with aircrack-ng tools.

Taking `README.md` from `wifte`, we have:

> Before you run wifite, please learn and use the command-line tools available with aircrack-ng. Here is an easy guide to WEP cracking and here is an easy guide to WPA cracking. Only after you have tested and successfully cracked WEP and WPA without the use of an automated tool should you use Wifite. This is for two reasons: 1. If it doesn't work, you blame Wifite. * Sometimes you have the wrong wireless drivers, an outdated version of aircrack-ng, or are missing important tools 1. When it does work, you actually know what it is doing. * Don't be a script kiddie. Understand the process being WEP and WPA cracking. I wrote this script for myself because remembering the aircrack-ng commands can be frustrating. Don't let this script enable you to be a script kiddie!

I highly recommend you to read the followings:

- http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=simple_wep_crack,
- https://www.rcis.aist.go.jp/files/project/ubicrypt-en/e91-b1_ieice07.pdf

And have deeper understading why `WPA` and `WEP` encryptions are not secure.